# Regular Expression To Find And Replace Text

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, find-and-replace

A file has hundreds of lines of text similar to the one below:

```
<Random Variable1="test" Description="this is a random description" number="12345" />
```

The value "<Random" at the start and the value "/>" at the end is the same on all lines of text.

I am trying to use regular expression to replace the /> symbol at the end with > and insert new lines of text underneath. An example of what the line from above needs to be replaced to:

```
<Random Variable1="test" Description="this is a random description" number="12345" >
         <Operating>
          <Operating>All</Operating>
        </Operating>
      </Random>
```

I have been testing with regular expressions but have not been successful, regular expressions I have tried to use:

To add in the new lines:

```
<Operating>\n<Operating>All</Operating>\n</Operating>\</Random>
```

To change the /> character:

```
<Random(.*) >
```

EDIT:
I am using the find and replace option within Visual Studio 17

Comment: Which language/tool are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your language/tool supports PCRE regex flavour, you can do:

- Find: `(?s)<Random\b.*?\K/>` or `<Random\b.*?\K/>` for multilines
- Replace: `><Operating>\n<Operating>All</Operating>\n</Operating>\n</Random>`

If it doesn't, use:

- Find: `(<Random\b.*?)/>`
- Replace: `$1><Operating>\n<Operating>All</Operating>\n</Operating>\n</Random>`

##### You may have to escape the `<` and `>`

- Find: `(\<Random\b.*?)/\>`

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Toto, I am using Visual Studio 17's find and replace tool. Visual Studios didn't seem to like the find regular expression as it didn't catch anything :(

Comment: Thank you, that works!